# Using gulp.src to match all subdirectories of a given directory, excluding given directory

Tags: regex, match, directory, subdirectory, gulp

I'm using gulp and gulp-chug to match all subdirectories of a given directory. What I want to perform is to watch several projects gulpfiles.

I want to match all gulpfile.js files inside subdirectories:

```
/path/to/dir/dir1/gulpfile.js
/path/to/dir/dir2/dir3/gulpfile.js
/path/to/dir/dir4/gulpfile.js
```

While excluding:

```
/path/to/dir/
```

I'm using the following pattern on gulp.src:

```
/path/to/dir/**/*.js
```

When I run the gulp task, I get the following error:

```
Unable to find local gulp. Try running 'npm install gulp' from /path/to/dir/.
```

Shouldn't /path/to/dir/ be excluded by the given pattern? Why is it looking for gulp on a directory that I don't want to be matched? Gulp is not installed on /path/to/dir/ because I don't want to search for gulpfiles on this directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Look again.  The error message actually tells you **what's wrong** *and* **how to fix it**.

You don't have the `gulp` npm package installed in your local project.  There's two parts to gulp.  The global `gulp` only installs the command-line application, you still need gulp installed within your project.

Go to your directory, and run the command it tells you to:

```shell
npm install gulp

// or, better run this:

npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Or, rather, follow the [installation instructions for gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#getting-started).

Comment: As I said, Gulp is not installed on /path/to/dir/ because I don't want to search for gulpfiles on this directory.

Besides, I'm running gulp command from a path outside /path/to/dir/ directory tree.

Comment: That's not what the error message is saying.  The message is saying you are running gulp from a directory without gulp installed.

Comment: No... it's saying gulp is not installed on /path/to/dir/. And it should not be. I'm running gulp with a gulp-chug task on another directory outside /path/to/dir/ directory tree and I want it to run on /path/to/dir/**/*.js, excluding /path/to/dir.

Comment: The directory you are in when you run gulp needs a local install of gulp.